# Build third party package in build or devel folder

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that needs to be unzipped, configured, and made. I currently do this inside my source folder. Then I jump through a bunch of hoops to make the dependencies depend on these custom commands.

The current problem I have is that it doesn't clean up. catkin_make clean doesn't delete the built products, and it doesn't delete the unzipped contents.

I could find some way to find the "clean" target, and do something special (like rm -rf unzipped location and build products) but that would probably confuse people because the rest of my build is out of source.

Ideally, I could unzip the source in the build folder somewhere, and then when the user deleted the build and devel folder, the next catkin_make would do a clean unzip and build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219006/build-third-party-package-in-build-or-devel-folder./) by [jeffeb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/24433/jeffeb3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeffeb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/24433/jeffeb3/) on 2015-10-12**:
I'm still hoping to find a way to install this into the build folder, but I did find a way to make the catkin_make clean delete the folder:

```
set_directory_properties(
  PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${EXTRACTED_DIR}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would agree that it would be better to do your download and custom logic in the build space. In general it's best practice that a build does not change the source space.

Since you're creating custom commands you should be able to do it in the build space instead of the source space.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeffeb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/24433/jeffeb3/) on 2015-10-12**:
Yeah, I'd like to do that. If you agree with my solution, then all I need is the syntax to get to the build folder. Is there a variable for the build folder?